# Trying to put an image in a container with the same color

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put an image with the container but I do not the image's transparent background to be shown. I want it to be with the green.

```css
#container {
  background-color: green;
  height: 70px;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img src="https://turbologo.com/articles/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/prozrachniy-logo-1-1280x720.png" alt="LOGO">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, it seems your problem is that your logo doesn't have a **real** transparent background.

The checkered boxes are, in fact, part of the image.

If you use an image that is transparent, such as the stackoverflow logo, you will see that your code will work just fine.

https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/so/logo-stackoverflow.png